# How to initialize several methods inside a python object

Tags: python

In a Javascript object when I would want to initiate several functions inside an object, say `myObject`, I would have an `init` function that would call those methods to me initialized and I would simple call `myObject.init()`. How would I do this in python? Would the following be ok?

```
class Test(object):
   def __init__(self, arg):
      self.arg = arg

   def init(self):
      self.some_function()
      self.some_other_function()

   def some_function(self):
      pass

   def some_other_function(self):
      pass

my_test = Test("test")
my_test.init()
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Yes, it will work. Just remember to call `init()` and not `__init__()`.

Comment: You'll still need the `self` argument for `init`, `some_function` and `some_other_function` (i.e. `def init(self):`), and in `init`, call `some_function` and `some_other_function` with `self.some_function()` and `self.some_other_function()`.

Comment: Thanks Christian! Thanks Warren I made corrections to my post based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That should work fine. but I would give some other name than init(), as it would be explicit and different from default `__init__`